# Como hago para que los números del input (range) aparezcan en la pantalla cada que lo disminuyo o lo aumento

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema y quiero que según modifique la barra del input cambie el el 40 de la pantalla  por el numero que disminuyo o aumento en la  barra  barra de rango  por alguna razon o me sale indefinido o me da error gracias

```js
function Mostrar() {
  let barraDeTiempo = document.getElementById(`barraDeTiempo`).value;
  let cajaNumeral = document.getElementById(`cajaNumeral`).value;
  barraDeTiempo.innerHTML = cajaNumeral;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Metronomo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p id="cajaNumeral"> 40 </p>
    </div>
    <span> 
            <input onclick="Mostrar()" id="barraDeTiempo" type="range" min="40" max="200" value="PPM">
            <button onclick="Stop()">Detener</button>
        </span>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas a corregir en tu código:

- No es recomendable poner los eventos en la misma etiqueta, porque complica el mantenimiento de tus scripts; es mejor si desde Javascript obtienes el elemento y asignas el evento con [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- Al menos para este caso, es mejor declarar variables de los elementos y obtener o asignar valor con sus propiedades y, de preferencia, fuera de la función, porque seguramente las vas a necesitar para otras acciones
- El valor del campo debe ser numérico y estás asignando texto `value="PPM"`
- Hay que saber las diferencias entre cada evento para saber cuál usar:

  - `click`: Solo cuando haces clic en determinada zona del campo, pero no al arrastrar
  - `change`: Solo al terminar de aplicar cambios (clic o después de arrastrar)
  - `input`: Siempre que se haga un cambio, ya sea con clic o mientras arrastras
- Con esta línea `barraDeTiempo.innerHTML = cajaNumeral;` estàs modificando la barra de tiempo con el texto del otro elemento; debe ser al revés, poner el valor de la barra como texto

```js
// Obtener elementos globales, fuera de la función
let barraDeTiempo = document.getElementById(`barraDeTiempo`);
let cajaNumeral = document.getElementById(`cajaNumeral`);
// Asignar evento a barra
barraDeTiempo.addEventListener('input', mostrar);
// Función para actualizar
function mostrar() {
    // Asignar a caja el valor de la barra
    cajaNumeral.innerHTML = barraDeTiempo.value;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <div>
      <p id="cajaNumeral">40</p>
    </div>
    <span> 
            <input id="barraDeTiempo" type="range" min="40" max="200" value="40">
            <button>Detener</button>
        </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda